# In istio , if the iptables only redirect outbound traffic, what will be happen?

Tags: traffic, istio, outbound

I am study istio recently.

In istio,  the inbound and outbound traffic from and to a pod was redirected
to envoy by iptables。thus, One request(or invoke) was proxied twice.

I found that the inbound traffic always consume the service in current pod.
in the other word,  the inbound traffic may not to be redirected to other pod again, it is neccesary to  proxy the inbound traffic?
If remove the rule for redirect the inbound traffic, does it work? 
or which function will be loss?

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Proxy-redirection) about Envoy proxy in/out bound traffic methods.

Answer (score 0):

Mixer is called by the inbound proxy, so if you bypass the Istio sidecar on inbound traffic you will lose the functions that Mixer implements: logging and checking such as ratelimits, auth, etc. Only routing is done on the outbound proxy.

Comment: I found the following one in istio_iptables: change the default behavior to not intercept any output.  not intercept any output?  what does it means? how to do?

Comment: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#calling-external-services-directly